# SQL max function without displaying max(..) in resulting table

Tags: sql, select, max

I have a `fake_apps` table:

```
id          INTEGER
name        TEXT
category    TEXT
downloads   INTEGER
price       REAL
```

I need to return the name and category of the app that has been downloaded the most amount of times.

A possible solution is:

```
SELECT name, category, max(downloads)
FROM fake_apps;
```

which will return something like this

```
name      |   category  |   max(downloads)
------------------------------------------
xyz       |   abc       |   100000
```

Now my question is: is there a way to use `max(downloads)` to filter the result without displaying it (net: I don't want max(downloads) to be displayed in the resulting table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like that:

`SELECT name, category FROM fake_apps WHERE downloads = (SELECT max(downloads) FROM fake_apps);`